# intel XDK camera view is not working

Tags: android, cordova, augmented-reality, intel-xdk

I am creating an augmented reality application using intel XDK.When I load the this app in the "Intel App Preview" app, I see a red background and no camera view when I hold my device in vertical position. Everything else seems to work.Why dont I see the camera view ?

This is my codes

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Nearby</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="Copyright" content="&copy; 2013, Intel Corporation. All rights reserved." />
    <meta name="Author" content="Nadeesha" />
<!--
 * Copyright (c) 2013, Intel Corporation. All rights reserved.
 * Please see http://software.intel.com/html5/license/samples 
 * and the included README.md file for license terms and conditions.
-->      
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />

    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
      <script src="intelxdk.js"></script>
    <script>
var pin = [
    {"name":"RUSL", "lat":"8.3635595", "lng":"80.5042495"},
    {"name":"Mihinthale", "lat":"8.35059440", "lng":"80.5169444"},
    {"name":"Mihintale Railway Station", "lat":"8.3589425", "lng":"80.50174530"},
    {"name":"Mihintale Forest Reserve", "lat":"8.3783333", "lng":"80.47916669"},
    {"name":"Mihintale Wewa", "lat":"8.3613889", "lng":"80.5052777"},
    {"name":"Mihintalekanda", "lat":"8.35000000", "lng":"80.500000"}
];        
var markersArray = [], bounds;
var myLat = 0, myLng = 0; 
var bearing, distance;
var dataStatus = 0;                

// setup map and listen to deviceready        
$( document ).ready(function() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
});

// start device compass, accelerometer and geolocation after deviceready        
function onDeviceReady() {
    navigator.splashscreen.hide();
    setupMap();
    // start cordova device sensors
    startAccelerometer();
    startCompass();
    startGeolocation();
}

        // start intel.xdk augmented reality mode, adds camera in background       
function xdkStartAR(){
    intel.xdk.display.startAR(); 
    $('#arView').css('background-color','transparent');
    $('body').css('background-color','transparent');
    document.getElementById('body').style.background = "transparent";
}

// stop intel.xdk augmented reality mode        
function xdkStopAR(){
    intel.xdk.display.stopAR(); 
}        


// setup google maps api        
function setupMap(){
    $("#map").height($(window).height()-60);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        navigationControl: true,
        scrollwheel: false,
        navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL},
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
}        

// toggle between list view and map view        
function toggleView(){
    if($(".listView").is(":visible")){
        $(".listView").hide();
        $("#map").height($(window).height()-60);
        $(".mapView").fadeIn(function(){google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");map.fitBounds(bounds);});
        $("#viewbtn").html("List");
    } else {
        $(".mapView").hide();
        $(".listView").fadeIn();
        $("#viewbtn").html("Map");
    }
}

// get data from API and store in array, add to list view and create markers on map, calculate         
function loadData(){
    dataStatus = "loading";
    markersArray = [];
    bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    // add blue gps marker
    var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png',new google.maps.Size(30, 28),new google.maps.Point(0,0),new google.maps.Point(9, 28));
    var gpsMarker = new google.maps.Marker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(myLat, myLng), map: map, title: "My Position", icon:icon});
    bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(myLat, myLng));
    markersArray.push(gpsMarker);
    // add all location markers to map and list view and array
    for(var i=0; i< pin.length; i++){
        $(".listItems").append("<div class='item'>"+pin[i].name+"</div>");
        addMarker(i);
        relativePosition(i);
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
    dataStatus = "loaded";   
}

// add marker to map and in array        
function addMarker(i){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(pin[i].lat, pin[i].lng), map: map, title: pin[i].name});
    bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(pin[i].lat, pin[i].lng));
    markersArray.push(marker);
} 

// clear all markers from map and array        
function clearMarkers() {
    while (markersArray.length) {
        markersArray.pop().setMap(null);
    }
}        

// calulate distance and bearing value for each of the points wrt gps lat/lng        
function relativePosition(i){
    var pinLat = pin[i].lat;
    var pinLng = pin[i].lng;
    var dLat = (myLat-pinLat)* Math.PI / 180;
    var dLon = (myLng-pinLng)* Math.PI / 180;
    var lat1 = pinLat * Math.PI / 180;
    var lat2 = myLat * Math.PI / 180;
    var y = Math.sin(dLon) * Math.cos(lat2);
    var x = Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2) - Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos(lat2)*Math.cos(dLon);
    bearing = Math.atan2(y, x) * 180 / Math.PI;
    bearing = bearing + 180;
    pin[i]['bearing'] = bearing;

    var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) + Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2); 
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
    distance = 3958.76  * c;
    pin[i]['distance'] = distance;
}

// calculate direction of points and display        
function calculateDirection(degree){
    var detected = 0;
    $("#spot").html("");
    for(var i=0;i<pin.length;i++){
        if(Math.abs(pin[i].bearing - degree) <= 20){
            var away, fontSize, fontColor;
            // varry font size based on distance from gps location
            if(pin[i].distance>1500){
                away = Math.round(pin[i].distance);
                fontSize = "16";
                fontColor = "#ccc";
            } else if(pin[i].distance>500){
                away = Math.round(pin[i].distance);
                fontSize = "24";
                fontColor = "#ddd";
            } else {
                away = pin[i].distance.toFixed(2);
                fontSize = "30";
                fontColor = "#eee";
            }
            $("#spot").append('<div class="name" data-id="'+i+'" style="margin-left:'+(((pin[i].bearing - degree) * 5)+50)+'px;width:'+($(window).width()-100)+'px;font-size:'+fontSize+'px;color:'+fontColor+'">'+pin[i].name+'<div class="distance">'+ away +' miles away</div></div>');
            detected = 1;
        } else {
            if(!detected){
                $("#spot").html("");
            }
        }
    }

} 

// Start watching the geolocation        
function startGeolocation(){
    var options = { timeout: 30000 };
    watchGeoID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onGeoSuccess, onGeoError, options);
}

// Stop watching the geolocation
function stopGeolocation() {
    if (watchGeoID) {
        navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchGeoID);
        watchGeoID = null;
    }
}

// onSuccess: Get the current location
function onGeoSuccess(position) {
    document.getElementById('geolocation').innerHTML = 'Latitude: ' + position.coords.latitude + '<br />' + 'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude;
    myLat = position.coords.latitude;
    myLng = position.coords.longitude;
    if(!dataStatus){
        loadData();
    }
}

// onError: Failed to get the location
function onGeoError() {
    document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += "onError=.";
} 

// Start watching the compass
function startCompass() {
    var options = { frequency: 100 };
    watchCompassID = navigator.compass.watchHeading(onCompassSuccess, onCompassError, options);
}

// Stop watching the compass
function stopCompass() {
    if (watchCompassID) {
        navigator.compass.clearWatch(watchCompassID);
        watchCompassID = null;
    }
}

// onSuccess: Get the current heading
function onCompassSuccess(heading) {
    var directions = ['N', 'NE', 'E', 'SE', 'S', 'SW', 'W', 'NW', 'N'];
    var direction = directions[Math.abs(parseInt((heading.magneticHeading) / 45) + 0)];
    document.getElementById('compass').innerHTML = heading.magneticHeading + "<br>" + direction;
    document.getElementById('direction').innerHTML = direction;
    var degree = heading.magneticHeading;
    if($("#arView").is(":visible") && dataStatus != "loading"){
        calculateDirection(degree);
    }
}

// onError: Failed to get the heading
function onCompassError(compassError) {
    document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += "onError=."+compassError.code;
}        

// Start checking the accelerometer
function startAccelerometer() {
    var options = { frequency: 100 };
    watchAccelerometerID = navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(onAccelerometerSuccess, onAccelerometerError, options);
}

// Stop checking the accelerometer
function stopAccelerometer() {
    if (watchAccelerometerID) {
        navigator.accelerometer.clearWatch(watchAccelerometerID);
        watchAccelerometerID = null;
    }
}

// onSuccess: Get current accelerometer values
function onAccelerometerSuccess(acceleration) {
    // for debug purpose to print out accelerometer values
    var element = document.getElementById('accelerometer');
    element.innerHTML = 'Acceleration X: ' + acceleration.x + '<br />' +
                        'Acceleration Y: ' + acceleration.y + '<br />' +
                        'Acceleration Z: ' + acceleration.z ;
    if(acceleration.y > 7){
        $("#arView").fadeIn();
        $("#topView").hide();
        document.getElementById('body').style.background = "#d22";
    } else {
        $("#arView").hide();
        $("#topView").fadeIn();
        document.getElementById('body').style.background = "#fff";
    }
}

// onError: Failed to get the acceleration
function onAccelerometerError() {
    document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += "onError.";
}
    </script>
    <style>
body {background-color:#fff;font-family:Arial;margin:0;overflow-x:hidden;-webkit-user-select: none;}
.navbar {background-color:#222;height:40px;padding:10px;text-align:center;color:#fff;font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;line-height:40px;}
.navtitle {text-align:center;margin:auto}
.navbtn {background-color:#333;padding:5px 10px;height:30px;color:#fff;font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;line-height:30px;border-radius:4px;border:1px solid #666} 
#actionbtn {float:right;}
#viewbtn {float:left;}
.query {padding:10px;background-color:#aaa;border-bottom:1px solid #fff;font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;color:#222;}
.item {padding:20px 10px; background-color:#eee;border-bottom:1px solid #fff;font-size:18px;color:#333;text-shadow:0 1px #fff}
.searchbox {padding:5px;background-color:#eee;border-bottom:1px solid #fff;}
#search {box-sizing: border-box;width:100%;height:40px;font-size:16px;border-radius:20px;border:1px solid #bbb}
.mapView {display:none}
#map {height:200px;}
#arView, #topView {display:none;}
#arView{padding:30px 0; height:70px;text-align:center}
.arMessage {color:#ddd;font-size:14px}
#spot {text-align:center}
.name, .distance {text-shadow:0 1px #666}
.name {padding:15px;font-weight:bold;;background-color:#c22;border-radius:40px;margin-bottom:10px}
#direction {color:#d55;font-size:20px;padding:15px;font-weight:bold;;background-color:#a22;border-radius:40px;display:inline-block;margin-bottom:10px;width:40px;line-height:40px}
.distance {font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;}
#debug {border:1px solid #999;display:none}
.heading {background-color:#999;color:#eee;padding:5px;}
#compass, #accelerometer, #geolocation {padding:5px}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body id="body">  
    <div id="arView">
        <div class="arMessage">&uarr;<br>Tilt down to see all places</div>
        <br>
        <div class="arMessage">&larr; Move the device around to find spots &rarr;</div>
        <br>
        <div id="direction"></div>
        <br>
        <div id="spot"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="topView">
        <div class="navbar">
            <div id="actionbtn" class="navbtn"> &crarr; </div>
            <div id="viewbtn" class="navbtn" onclick="toggleView()">Map</div>    
            <div class="navtitle">Nearby</div> 
        </div>
        <div class="listView">
            <div class="listItems"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="mapView">
            <div id="map"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="debug">  
        <div class="heading">Geolocation</div>
        <div id="geolocation"></div>
        <div class="heading">Compass</div>
        <div id="compass"></div>
        <div class="heading">Accelerometer</div>
        <div id="accelerometer"></div>
        <div class="heading">Log</div>
        <div id="log"></div>
    </div>      
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I try your app, all I get is a blank white screen.  Is there more to it than what you've posted?  If you could pare it down to just the camera part that's failing, that would make it a lot easier to try.

Comment: There's a sample app here - https://github.com/krisrak/html5-augmented-reality-app.  Does that one work for you, or do you still just see a red screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not calling `xdkStartAR()` and `xdkStopAR()` in function `onAccelerometerSuccess` so the camera is not initiating.

Here is the correct `onAccelerometerSuccess`:

```
function onAccelerometerSuccess(acceleration) {
    // for debug purpose to print out accelerometer values
    var element = document.getElementById('accelerometer');
    element.innerHTML = 'Acceleration X: ' + acceleration.x + '<br />' +
                        'Acceleration Y: ' + acceleration.y + '<br />' +
                        'Acceleration Z: ' + acceleration.z ;
    if(acceleration.y > 7){
        $("#arView").fadeIn();
        $("#topView").hide();
        document.getElementById('body').style.background = "#d22";
        xdkStartAR();
    } else {
        $("#arView").hide();
        $("#topView").fadeIn();
        document.getElementById('body').style.background = "#fff";
        xdkStopAR();
    }
}
```

Also I had to include `intelxdk.js` first and then `cordova.js` to get it to work in app preview:

> ```
> <script src="intelxdk.js"></script>
> <script src="cordova.js"></script>
> ```

Comment: Thank u very much for answering,I have an  issue with XDK ,when I change my code IDE it stop working and shows (Intel XDK encountered a problem and must restart),Do you have any suggestion to prevent that,(I am learning from your coding on git repo)

Comment: yes it happens every time when I change my code,When I go to the emulator and rotate it ,at the layer which should show the AR only display 2 buttons 'select a file' & 'cancel'.and when I refresh the page it shows that error message too.

Comment: intelxdk ARmode is a plugin, it will not work correctly in emulator, you have to test on app preview, or comment out xdkStartAR() during development